# Python TK library horizontal scroll bar not showing

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-layout

I am really new to TK library. I have the following code, but horizontal scroll bar does not show. Can anyone see why? Any help is appreciated!

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
container = ttk.Frame(root)
canvas = tk.Canvas(container)
scrollbar_y = ttk.Scrollbar(container, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
scrollbar_x = ttk.Scrollbar(container, orient="horizontal", command=canvas.xview)
scrollable_frame = ttk.Frame(canvas)

scrollable_frame.bind(
    "<Configure>",
    lambda e: canvas.configure(
        scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")
    )
)

canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=scrollable_frame, anchor="nw")

canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar_y.set, xscrollcommand=scrollbar_x.set)

for i in range(50):
    ttk.Label(scrollable_frame, text="Sample scrolling label").pack()

container.pack()
canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
scrollbar_y.pack(side="right", fill="y")
scrollbar_x.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code is working. Just add more string. `ttk.Label(scrollable_frame, text="Sample scrolling labelSample scrolling labeSample scrolling labeSample scrolling labeSample scrolling labeSample scrolling labeSample scrolling labeSample scrolling labeSample scrolling labes").pack()`

Answer (score 1):

problem solved:

had to replace

```
self.x_scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.container, orient="horizontal", command=self.canvas.xview)
```

with

```
self.x_scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.master, orient="horizontal", command=self.canvas.xview)
```

So that the scrollbar can show up on the bottom instead of being buried in the frame.